# How to execute two code fragments in different sequence?

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

I have a code with next logic: If some boolean flag is true, one of two code fragments must be executed first and vice versa. But both of them must be executed always. Unfortunately, C# has not semantics instructions for that, like this:

```
if (condition) first
{
//Some code to execute first if condition is true
}
second
{
//Some code to execute first if condition is false
}
```

Now, I to do so:

```
if (condition)
{
//Code 1
//Code 2
}
else
{
//Code 2
//Code 1
}
```

Such neccesserities are numerous and this creates many code duplication. May be is there a better solution?

Comment: can't you create a method runCode1() and another one runCode2() then you simply call these methods in proper order without having to write/implement them twice?

Comment: What is the method signature of these methods?  You might be able to do something neater with delegates.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the reason for the order sometimes needing to be reversed? I sense an underlying design issue which could be resolved better on a higher level.

Answer (score 3):

Put the code into seperate methods

```
public void MyMethod1
{
   //first code goes here
}

public void MyMethod2
{
   //second code goes here
}


if (condition)
{
  MyMethod1();
  MyMethod2();
}
else
{
  MyMethod2();
  MyMethod1();
}
```

This way you do not have to duplicate the code inside the methods.

Comment: When reading his question, I'm suspecting he isn't already doing it that way ;)

Answer (score 2):

You may consider writing a method such as:

```
public static void DoBoth(Action first, Action second, bool keepOrder)
    {
        if (keepOrder)
        {
            first();
            second();
        }
        else
        {
            second();
            first();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Best DRY solution of the bunch, considering that the OP indicates _"Such neccesserities are numerous and this creates many code duplication."_. This solves the fact the it occurs in many places. I would probably make the method private, or even a lambda though. If it happens throughout an entire project, I'd consider a redesign.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create two methods with "Code 1" and "Code 2", then go on like your 2nd option:

```
if (condition)
{
Code1(); Code2();
}
else
{
Code 2(); Code1();
}
```

You could also polish this up via Actions or Delegates, depending on what "code 1" and "code 2" are.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Steven Jeuris comment about preferring to know the underlying reason as it may point to a design decision requiring improvement. However, if you need to stick with what you have, I would suggest a queue of delegates since you imply that your example is very simple compared to the *actual* codebase. If not, then one of the other answers would be fine, but the below is possibly more maintainable as complexity grows.

Note: I'm putting this as an example - the parameters for GetQueue, and the logic inside it, could be improved depending on what your conditions actually are.

```
public Queue<Action> GetQueue(bool condition)
{
    var toReturn = new Queue<Action>();
    if (condition)
    {
        toReturn.Enqueue(DoWork1);
        toReturn.Enqueue(DoWork2);
    }
    else
    {
        toReturn.Enqueue(DoWork2);
        toReturn.Enqueue(DoWork1);
    }
    return toReturn;
}

public void MyExecutingMethod()
{
    foreach (var action in GetQueue(true))
    {
        action();
    }
}

public void DoWork1()
{

}

public void DoWork2()
{

}
```

Comment: This is a good approach when you want to setup the behavior prior to executing it, but shouldn't be used for anything else than that. +1 nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid code duplication whenever you can. The basic idea in your case would be to try and extract everything that seems to be done more than once and try to "put" it somewhere where you only need to write it once.

In your case, say we have the following:

```
 public void Bar()
 {
     ...
     if (condition)
     {
         //code for action 1
         //code for action 2
     }
     else
     {
         //code for action 2
         //code for action 1
     }
     ...
 }

 public void Foo()
 {
     ...
     if (condition)
     {
         //code for action 1
         //code for action 2
     }
     else
     {
         //code for action 2
         //code for action 1
     }
     ...
 }
```

Now we obviously can see that you have some code duplication here. We can improve this the following way:

```
 public void Bar()
 {
     ...
     if (condition)
     {
         Action1();
         Action2();
     }
     else
     {
         Action2();
         Action1();
     }
     ...
 }

 public void Foo()
 {
     ...
     if (condition)
     {
         Action1();
         Action2();
     }
     else
     {
         Action2();
         Action1();
     }
     ...
 }

 private void Action1()
 {
     //code for action 1
 }

 private void Action2()
 {
     //code for action 1
 }
```

This looks a lot better (specially if `Action1` code and `Action2` code is lengthy). We have now managed to write the code for `Action1` and `Action2` only once no matter how many `Foo` or `Bar` style methods we have in our code. But we can still do more. You can see that we are still duplicating some obnoxious verbose code. So we can take it a step further and do the following:

```
 public void Bar()
 {
     ...
     DoAction(condition);
     ...
 }

 public void Foo()
 {
     ...
     DoAction(condition);
     ...
 }

 private void Action1()
 {
     //code for action 1
 }

 private void Action2()
 {
     //code for action 1
 }

 private void DoAction(bool condition)
 {
      if (condition)
      {
           Action1();
           Action2();
      }
      else
      {
           Action2();
           Action1();
      }
 }
```

Now, that IMHO looks a lot better. Not only have we managed to write `Action1` and `Action2` specific code only once, we have now also managed to write that pesky method ordering logic only once too.

This has huge implications on readability and above all maintainability. For instance, if a bug crops up in `Action1` now you only need to change it in one single place. In the original implementation you would have to check all the code and fix the bug everywhere.

Also, imagine the method ordering is business rules dependant, and your client (oh my what a surprise!) decides to change them. With the latest implementation you only need to change your code in one spot.

Rule of the thumb: Avoid code duplication whenever you can, it will drastically reduce the code you type and the headaches you or some poor soul will have in the near future.

Comment: +1 for the walk-through. Depending on the specific code I would use this approach or [rich.okelly's](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8269615/590790) solution which is a bit more generalized. (Allows calling not just two methods.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to hazard a guess that code1 either have no side effects or act on the classes member variables, in which case they can be wrapped up in methods that return void. You could then do something along the lines of the following:

```
...
    if (condition)
        DoWork(() => Code1(), () => Code2());
    else
    {
        DoWork(() => Code2(), () => Code1());
    }
...

private void Code1()
{
    // Code 1
}

private void Code2()
{
    // code 2
}

private void DoWork(Action action1, Action action2)
{
    action1();
    action2();
}
```

Comment: What is the added benefit over calling the functions directly?

Comment: IMHO Neater code - I'm not quite sure why my solution warrants a down vote since it is perfectly valid. Oh well...

Comment: `DoWork(() => Code1(), () => Code2());` is neater than `Code1(); Code2();`? Is your intention that by making it one statement you can remove the braces?

Comment: It's subjective, which is why I added 'IMHO' to my comment.

Comment: I don't see how it is subjective. You redirect a call for no other reason than to call the redirected call. If I add yet another extra layer of indirection and prefer that, would that be subjective? `Call(() => DoWork(() => Code1(), () => Code2()))`

Comment: Ok, maybe look up subjective in the dictionary and then come back to me.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase that. There are clear objective reasons not to do what you are saying. Your subjective opinion can be countered by objective arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I offer another suggestion (in pseudocode).

EDIT: It really depends on your situation which of various approaches you will want to take. Benefits of this approach are simplicity and flexibility. By flexibility, I mean that the decision on ordering is now separated from the code so you can easily do things like add a new ordering, or let the ordering be specified in some other means (e.g. what if you now want to associate different orderings with different users based on a property file)?

```
if(condition)
       runOrder = [ "one", "two" ];
else
       runOrder = [ "two", "one" ];

for(x=0; x<runOrder.length; x++)
{
     codeToRun = runOrder[x];
     switch(codeToRun)
     {
              Case "one": Code1();
              Case "two": Code2();
     }
}
```

Comment: Same comment as on [s1mm0t's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8269682/590790): _"What is the added benefit over calling the functions directly?"_

Comment: @StevenJeuris In my opinion, it makes it easier to maintain and the code is cleaner. It would really depend on the exact situation though. But it separates the ordering issue from the code. For example, what if we have some extra code that can't be put into Code1() or Code2()... what I have in mind is, what if we need to have separate try blocks around Code1() and Code2()?

Comment: I see, you mean something along the likes of [Alex's](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8269925/590790) answer. Indeed, depending on the exact situation splitting the order of the code from it's execution could make sense. Alex's answer is cleaner in that aspect, but I'll remove the down vote. ;p Consider clarifying that part of your answer a bit.

Comment: Yes, his works too. All different ways of doing it which really depend on the flexibility and complexity needed. The exact approach will take some critical thinking on the part of the person asking regarding their scenario... but I'm sure having all these different options on here will be useful to future users with a similar problem.